# How do I launch a java process that has the standard bash shell environment?

Tags: java, bash, shell, process, environment

I've tried looking into process builder, but I'm not sure how to source the bash environment into the process.

For example I'm using the following to launch my process:

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder(args).start();
InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
```

And I'd like my standard shell environment (from /etc/profile, .bashrc, etc.) sourced to the process.

Sorry if I'm not using the right terms - still learning java.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Its likely to be an option like `bash -l` if you don't have the right environment already. Is there any reason you don't have the bash environment before you start Java?

Comment: Not totally clear here... do you mean that you are writing a Java program that will execute a `bash` shell as a child process?

Comment: Maybe execute command like: `/usr/bin/env bash -c ". /etc/bash.bashrc; cmd"`

Comment: @erickson please see update - I'd like to do exactly what you state here in the comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set up a shell invocation with ProcessBuilder. Execute a command like:

```
/bin/bash -l -c "The entire command line that you want to execute"
```

When constructing the`ProcessBuilder` pay attention to pass the command to execute as one unified string, e.g:

```sh
new ProcessBuilder("bash", "-l", "-c", "ps ax")
```

Answer (score 0):

Go and get the latest [Beanshell](http://www.beanshell.org/manual/bshmanual.html) .jar  file and put it into your Javasoft/jre/lib/ext  directory.

Then , you can run Java shell scripts like this:

```
java bsh.Interpreter myscript.bsh [args]
```

Or, from within a Java program like so:

```
Object result = new bsh.Interpreter().source("myscript.bsh");
```

NOTE: in the second example, the args need to be set separately in the namespace.

Comment: thanks! will this type of bash environment automatically source the standard environment from /etc/profile or does that need to be called separately?

Comment: It depends on what you do.  If you dont invoke any of Beanshells dynamic classpath methods in your Java Beanshell script , then the default classloader is used and the environment from the bash shell is accessible (such as CLASSPATH).

Answer (score 0):

You can try,

```
bash -i -c "your command"
```

Here i stands for interactive screen, which will start by executing the commands present in the `~/.bashrc file`