# mvn command not found when running python script from Java

Tags: java, linux, shell, maven

Currently I am able to launch a python program in java using `Process`.

The problem is that, `Process` cannot recognize `mvn` command in the python program, although I have maven installed properly and was able to run python program from terminal.

This is how I use `Process`:

```
public static String runCommand(String directory, List<String> command) {

    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command).directory(new File(directory));

    processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);

    Process process;
    String output = null;
    try {
        process = processBuilder.start();


        //Pause the current thread until the process is done
        process.waitFor();

        //When the process does not exit properly
        if (process.exitValue() != 0) {

            //Error
            System.out.println("command exited in error: " + process.exitValue());

            //Handle the error
            return readOutput(process);
        }else {

            output = readOutput(process);
            System.out.println(output);
        }

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("Something wrong with command: " +e.getMessage());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Something wrong with command: " +e.getMessage());
    }

    return output;
}`
```

Driver code:

```
    List<String> csi = new ArrayList<>();
    CSI_PATH = getClass().getResource("/python/csi").getPath();
    System.out.println("CSI path:" + CSI_PATH);


    //Construct the argument
    csi.add(CSI_PATH);
    //argument for the csi program
    csi.add(pre_hash);
    csi.add(post_hash);

    String csi_output = Command.runCommand(project_directory, csi);

    System.out.println(csi_output);
```

Is there anything I can do in Java to let the `Process` to recognize `mvn` inside the python program?

relevant part of csi program:

```
os.sys_call("git checkout " + commit_hash)
os.sys_call("mvn clean")
bin_path = mvn.path_from_mvn_call("outputDirectory")
src_rel_path = mvn.path_from_mvn_call("sourceDirectory")


def path_from_mvn_call(env):
    if env not in ["sourceDirectory", "scriptSourceDirectory", "testSourceDirectory", 
               "outputDirectory", "testOutputDirectory", "directory"]:
        raise ValueError("incorrect env var: " + env)
    mvn_cmd = "mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.build." + env + " | grep ^/"
    return subprocess.check_output(mvn_cmd, shell=True).strip()

def sys_call(cmd, ignore_bad_exit=False):
    ret = subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
    if ret != 0:
        print "\n-- << non-zero exit status code >> --"
        if ignore_bad_exit:
            print "Exit from command: \n\t" + cmd
            print "But we can safely ignore such non-zero exit status code this time.\n"
        else:
            print "Error in command: \n\t" + cmd + "\n"
            raise SystemExit("system exit: " + str(ret))
```

Thx in advance!

Edit: 
I have tried this post 
[How do I launch a java process that has the standard bash shell environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354592/how-do-i-launch-a-java-process-that-has-the-standard-bash-shell-environment)

So I changes the code to

```
      //Construct the argument
      csi.add("/bin/bash");
      csi.add("-l");
      csi.add("-c");
      csi.add("\"" + csi_path + " " + pre_hash+ " " + post_hash + "\"");
      String csi_output = Command.runCommand(project_directory, csi);
```

But even so the command exits by 127, which means `Value 127 is returned by your shell /bin/bash when any given command within your bash script or on bash command line is not found in any of the paths defined by PATH system environment variable.`

If I run `/bin/bash -l -c "mvn --version"` in java, it still exited 127.

Comment: Please show some relevant code.

Comment: @OldProgrammer Thx for the reminder, I have added the relevant code.

Answer (score -1):

Python inherits the all environment from your terminal. a subprocess spawned from Python should inherit the all environment from the parent process. So I am not sure why the error occur mvn. 
you can try python subprocess :

```
import subprocess
args = ['mvn', '-version']
process = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

or

```
import subprocess
args = ['mvn', '-version']
process = subprocess.Popen(args,shell=True)
```