# Adding double quotes symbol in ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, bash, shell

I am using `ProcessBuilder`to build my command. I want to build my command following this post:[How do I launch a java process that has the standard bash shell environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354592/how-do-i-launch-a-java-process-that-has-the-standard-bash-shell-environment)

Namely, my command is something like this:
`/bin/bash -l -c "my program"`

However, I am having difficulties to pass the double quotes into `ProcessBuilder`, as `new ProcessBuilder(List<String> command)` failed to phrase the command if I natively add double quotes to `List<String> command`. `ProcessBuilder` recognizes the double quotes as an argument.

Relevant code:

```
    //Construct the argument
    csi.add("/bin/bash");
    csi.add("-l");
    csi.add("-c");
    csi.add("\"");
    csi.add(csi_path);
    csi.add(pre_hash);
    csi.add(post_hash);
    csi.add("\"");

    String csi_output = Command.runCommand(project_directory, csi);

 public static String runCommand(String directory, List<String> command) {


    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command).directory(new File(directory));
    Process process;
    String output = null;
    try {
        process = processBuilder.start();

        //Pause the current thread until the process is done
        process.waitFor();

        //When the process does not exit properly
        if (process.exitValue() != 0) {

            //Error
            System.out.println("command exited in error: " + process.exitValue());

            //Handle the error
            return readOutput(process);
        }else {

            output = readOutput(process);
            System.out.println(output);
        }

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("Something wrong with command: " +e.getMessage());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Something wrong with command: " +e.getMessage());
    }

    return output;
}
```

Ps: I do want to use `ProcessBuilder` instead of `Runtime.getRuntime.exec()` because I need to run the command in a specific directory. I need to use `ProcessBuilder.directory()`.

Ps: The command will exit with 2 after running. It seems that the system can recognize this command. The strange thing is that it has no output after exiting with 2.

Ps: The expected command is `/bin/bash -l -c "/Users/ryouyasachi/GettyGradle/build/idea-sandbox/plugins/Getty/classes/python/csi 19f4281 a562db1"`. I printed the value and it was correct.

Comment: You shouldn't need to. Each element in the `List` will be passed as a individual argument to the command, so just pass a `List<String>` to the `ProcessBuilder`

Comment: To my mind, that would mean changing `new ProcessBuilder(sb.toString())` to `new ProcessBuilder(command)`

Comment: Remember, the reason for using `"..."` on the command line, is to negate the white space, so everything between the quotes is passed as a single argument to the process

Comment: @MadProgrammer I tried your way but the command still exited with 2. It seems that the problem is adding `/bin/bash -l -c` since `my program` runs normal without it.

Comment: @JiaxiangLiang update your post with what you recently tried.

Comment: @JiaxiangLiang also, mention your actual command to the post and verify your variable value which you are adding to the list

Comment: @Ravi I updated. `new ProcessBuilder(command)` is the only change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to troubleshoot your problem is to construct the command first and pass it to the list. So, instead of doing all this.

```
csi.add("/bin/bash");
csi.add("-l");
csi.add("-c");
csi.add("\"");
csi.add(csi_path);
csi.add(pre_hash);
csi.add(post_hash);
csi.add("\"");
```

You should first construct the command

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("/bin/bash -l -c");
sb.append("\""+csi_path+pre_hash+post_hash+"\"");// add whitespace between the varaible, if required.
System.outprintln(sb.toString());  //verify your command here

csi.add(sb.toString());
```

Also, verify all above variable values.

Comment: I tried your approach. It seems that it cannot recognize the "/bin/bash -l -c". The output is `Cannot run program "/bin/bash -l -c" (in directory "/Users/ryouyasachi/Getty/semantiful-differentials-getty/getty/dsproj"): error=2, No such file or directory`

Comment: Also, I have mentioned multiple times, please verify your variables

Comment: Also, please note, using processbuilder, you changed the `pwd` to `/Users/ryouyasachi/Getty/semantiful-differentials-getty/get‌​ty/dsproj`. So, you need to try executing `/bin/bash -l -c` command from there. If not executing then, it isn't your java code issue.

Comment: You need to come up with actual command and try manually first and then that need to simulate in java code. Do not do it in reverse order otherwise you will always face this issue

Comment: I was able to run it from my terminal. The variables were fine too, I double checked it.

Comment: So, you are saying, the command you get from java output is working fine on terminal. Am I right ?

Comment: Why I wants to run `/bin/bash -l -c` is this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45250281/mvn-command-not-found-when-running-python-script-from-java

Comment: forget about what mentioned in other post, the question is whether same command is working on terminal or not (which you get from java output ) ?

Comment: Yes, if I print the command & copy paste to my terminal, it runs fine.

Comment: Then, you need to minimize the code and debug each line and see what does your command getting abnormal termination. Because, we don't have access to your environment.

Comment: And, by looking at your code everything looks fine. That could be some other reason.. that you should debug now.

Answer (score 0):

Thx for @Ravi 's idea!

```
    //Construct the argument
    csi.add("/bin/bash");
    csi.add("-l");
    csi.add("-c");
    csi.add("\"" + csi_path + " " + pre_hash+ " " + post_hash + "\"");


    String csi_output = Command.runCommand(project_directory, csi);
```

The `Process` has to take each argument separately in order to recognize the command. The tricky part is that, in my desired command
`/bin/bash -l -c "/mypath/csi"`

`"/mypath/csi"` needs to be viewed as one single argument by `Process`.